Is there a catalog of known solutions to the Inverse Lagrangian problem?
I have been researching Lagrangian mathematics and variations on it.  The most traditional Lagrangian, $L=T-V$ works for systems that have only conservative forces. A handful of non-conservative cases support a potential $V$ which allows this Lagrangian to function.
There is also the general question, the Inverse problem of Lagrangian mechanics.  Basically, a question of which second order differential equations have a solution defined by the Euler-Lagrange formula.  This problem is theoretically solved.  The Helmhotz conditions are necessary and sufficient.  However, they are extremely difficult to prove in general.
Is there a catalog of known special cases where a Lagrangian has been proven to exist?
